# Expanding existing point grid to cover larger area in ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.5, vector-grid

I am looking to expand the already existing point grid system to encompass the entire polygon pictured below without changing the existing point locations or label features.

Is there a tool in ArcGIS Desktop that will allow for the expansion of an already existing grid?

I am running on ArcGIS Desktop 10.5.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think the technique will be to use Create Fishnet to create 4 adjacent “rectangles” of new points in new feature classes for each direction that you wish to expand in, and then to Append your 5 feature classes together.

Comment: Excellent suggestion. Thank you. I would need to expand in all cardinal directions.

Comment: Your grid looks to be rotated from north so it does not look like you would be expanding in cardinal directions.